# Setting datetime data type on a View in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a view in an SQLite database that is missing data types for some of the columns when it gets created.  It appears that what happens is the data type is lost anytime a function is run against datetime columns such as using MAX, COALESCE, etc...

As an example the following would create a view that preserves data types.

```
CREATE VIEW foo_view AS
SELECT created_at, updated_at FROM "the_table"
```

But the following will result in the datetime data type being lost.

```
CREATE VIEW bar_view AS
SELECT coalesce(created_at, updated_at) as wut FROM "the_table"
```

Is there some way to preserve or set the datatype when creating the view in this second fashion where I need to perform operations on the data that will end up in the view?

Comment: What would you need the column type information for?

Comment: In this case the SQLite database is used in our test environment for a Ruby on Rails application.  ActiveRecord uses the data type to convert the data into an approriate Ruby data type; in this instance it should be a DateTime object in Ruby.  When there is no data type then it is set to a String object in Ruby.  I would imagine other ORMs behave similarly.

Comment: SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and does not have column types; if ActiveRecord assumes otherwise, it's buggy.

Comment: The dynamic typing in SQLite is on a per value basis; to maintain as much compatibility with SQL and other relational storage engines as possible SQLite supports type affinity.  So if I create a table in SQLite and declare datatypes for those columns they will have the correct type affinity.   If I create a view in SQLite and a column is 1 to 1 mapped then SQLite will infer the correct type affinity.  My question is how can I get SQLite to have the correct type affinity in these more complex cases as I have described.

Comment: In the general case, [expression do not have any affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity_of_comparison_operands), and ActiveRecord should not assume otherwise.